# Let $S$ be the subspace of $P_3$ consisting of all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(0) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $S$ be the subspace of $P_3$ consisting of all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(0) = 0$, and let $T$ be the subspace of all polynomials $q(x)$ such that $q(1) = 0.$ Find a basis for $S$.

The answer is $\{x,x^2\}$.

*I want to ask:*
if $S$ is a subspace of $P_3$, why the answer is not $\{x,x^2,x^3\}\,$?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Perhaps there is a typo in the question. The answer may be for $P_2$.

Comment: Or maybe $P_d$ is the space of polynomials of degree $<d$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Several authors define $P_n$ as the vector space of polynomials whose degree is *smaller* than $n$, so that $\dim P_n=n$.